# Limiting CPUs with nthreads in H2O R.

Tags: r, h2o

I am using H2O with R. When defining nthreads, the commands are using more than the threads determined. This is my code:

> library(h2o)
>
> h2o.init(nthreads=8)

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /tmp/RtmpklPi6J/h2o_mballesta_started_from_r.out
    /tmp/RtmpklPi6J/h2o_mballesta_started_from_r.err

openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: . Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster:
    H2O cluster uptime:         23 seconds 421 milliseconds
    H2O cluster timezone:       Europe/Madrid
    H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
    H2O cluster version:        3.20.0.2
    H2O cluster version age:    11 days
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_mballesta_knw859
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1
    H2O cluster total memory:   26.67 GB
    H2O cluster total cores:    32
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  8
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost
    H2O Connection port:        54321
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE
    H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
    R Version:                  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
```

The allowed cores are 8. But when sending a command, it can use up to 24 cores ([image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3CTG.jpg)). How can I limit the maximum number of cores? I am using Linux CentOS.

Comment: What you are doing is correct.  What are you doing inside H2O?  (It just occurred to me that xgboost inside H2O might not honor the nthreads request, since it’s not implemented in Java.)

Comment: This problem occurs with any command in my case. In my script I use "as.h2o", "h2o.splitFrame", "h2o.grid" and, "h2o.deeplearning" functions. All of them exceed the nthreads.